# When partial view render in main view, an error occurs in ASP.NET MVC framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[WebApplication2.Models.AttendanceShow]'

Comment: Please show your .cshtml code and controller action

Comment: Clearly the view is expecting a model and you are sending it a string